# Error requiring luasocket on socket.core file installed through Luarocks on Windows

Tags: visual-studio-2010, lua, luasocket, luarocks

System configuration:

```
OS: Windows 7 x64

lua -v
  Lua 5.1.4

luarocks -v
  2.2.0beta1

luarocks list
  luasocket
    3.0rc1-1 (installed) - C:/Program Files (x86)/LuaRocks/systree/lib/luarocks/rocks

luarocks show luasocket
   LuaSocket 3.0rc1-1 - Network support for the Lua language

    LuaSocket is a Lua extension library that is composed by two parts: a C core
    that provides support for the TCP and UDP transport layers, and a set of Lua
    modules that add support for functionality commonly needed by applications that
    deal with the Internet.

    License:        MIT
    Homepage:       http://luaforge.net/projects/luasocket/
    Installed in:   C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\systree

    Modules:
        ltn12 (C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\systree/share/lua/5.1/ltn12.lua)
        mime (C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\systree/share/lua/5.1/mime.lua)
        mime.core (C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\systree/lib/lua/5.1/mime/core.dll)
        socket (C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\systree/share/lua/5.1/socket.lua)
        socket.core (C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\systree/lib/lua/5.1/socket/core.dll)
        socket.ftp (C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\systree/share/lua/5.1/socket/ftp.lua)
        socket.headers (C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\systree/share/lua/5.1/socket/headers.lua)
        socket.http (C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\systree/share/lua/5.1/socket/http.lua)
        socket.smtp (C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\systree/share/lua/5.1/socket/smtp.lua)
        socket.tp (C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\systree/share/lua/5.1/socket/tp.lua)
        socket.url (C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\systree/share/lua/5.1/socket/url.lua)

luarocks path
  SET LUA_PATH=C:\Users\Zequez\AppData\Roaming/luarocks/share/lua/5.1/?.lua;
  C:\Users\Zequez\AppData\Roaming/luarocks/share/lua/5.1/?/init.lua;
  C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\systree/share/lua/5.1/?.lua;
  C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\systree/share/lua/5.1/?/init.lua;
  C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\2.2\lua\?.lua;
  C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\2.2\lua\?\init.lua;
  SET LUA_CPATH=C:\Users\Zequez\AppData\Roaming/luarocks/lib/lua/5.1/?.dll;
  C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\systree/lib/lua/5.1/?.dll;
  .\?.dll;
  .\?51.dll;
  C:\ProgramFiles (x86)\LuaRocks\2.2\?.dll;
  C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\2.2\?51.dll;
  C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\2.2\clibs\?.dll;
  C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\2.2\clibs\?51.dll;
  C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\2.2\loadall.dll;
  C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\2.2\clibs\loadall.dll
      SET LUA_CPATH=C:\Users\Zequez\AppData\Roaming/luarocks/lib/lua/5.1/?.dll;
  C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\systree/lib/lua/5.1/?.dll;
  .\?.dll;
  .\?51.dll;
  C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\2.2\?.dll;
  C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\2.2\?51.dll;
  C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\2.2\clibs\?.dll;
  C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\2.2\clibs\?51.dll;
  C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\2.2\loadall.dll;
  C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\2.2\clibs\loadall.dll
```

I'm new to Lua, and I'm not used to compiling stuff on Windows.

Anyway the installaion of `luasocket` finished without errors, compiling all the stuff with MS Visual Studio 2010. Had to run `luarocks` from the Visual Studio Command Prompt, but it finally worked.

But when I try to require it, I drive into an error.

```
> require 'socket'
error loading module 'socket.core' from file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\systree/lib/lua/5.1/socket\core.dll':
        C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\systree/lib/lua/5.1/socket\core.dll:1: '=' expected near 'É'
stack traceback:
        [C]: ?
        [C]: in function 'require'
        ...iles (x86)\LuaRocks\systree/share/lua/5.1/socket.lua:12: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'require'
        stdin:1: in main chunk
        [C]: ?
```

Using `require 'luarocks.loader'` doesn't help either, same error. I think I don't need it anyway, because I have LUA_PATH set up with the `luarocks` paths

I searched for hours with no results. I also tried to install an older version of Luasockets but it requires Visual Studio 2003, so I would like to avoid that.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like Lua is trying to parse the DLL as Lua code. This can happen if `package.path` (or the `LUA_PATH` environment variable) contains `?.dll` path templates. Please remove all `?.dll` templates from `package.path` and put them into `package.cpath` (or the `LUA_CPATH` environment variable).